# NPM cross-env not installed

Tags: npm, npm-install

I have the following package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --watch-poll --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "installreact": "npm install react react-dom --save",
    "installbabel": "npm install babel-core babel-loader babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react --save-dev",
    "installwebpack": "npm install webpack webpack-dev-server --save-dev",
    "build": "webpack -d && webpack-dev-server --content-base src/ --inline --hot --port 1234"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "cross-env": "^5.1.4",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "laravel-mix": "^1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "vue": "^2.1.10",
    "webpack": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "material-ui": "^1.0.0-beta.38",
    "material-ui-icons": "^1.0.0-beta.36",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "redux": "^3.7.2"
  }
}
```

When I run npm install, `cross-env` directory is not created in `node_modules` and there is no error. Only message: up to date in 1.337s.

I tried to uninstall and install the package again, but nothing changes.

Comment: Install it globaly. _npm install -g cross-env_

Comment: could you try once by running `npm nstall cross-env@5.1.4` command. then check for the specified directory. if it is available then remove the `^` in front of package version in `package.json` file and then try `npm install`.

Answer (score 3):

my issue resolved with

1:You have cross-env as a dependency in your package.json

2:Delete the folders cross-env and cross-spawn from node_modules folder.

3:Make sure you haven't got a .npmrc file with bin-links options set to
 false.
 (Running npm config ls -l will show you all the implicit settings for
 npm, including what it thinks is the right place to put the .npmrc.
 But if you have never logged in (using npm login) it will be empty.
 Simply log in to create it.)

4:`Run npm install` again.

Comment: Deleting the reference to cross-env in devDependencies and reinstalling worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Install it globally like I said above or run it using the path. However, npm should set everything in bin folder in the path when running npm script.

```
"dev": "./node_modules/.bin/cross-env ..."
```

If the cross-env executable is not within the bin folder. Make sure about 3 things:

- You have *cross-env* as a dependency in your package.json
- Delete the folders *cross-env* and *cross-spawn* from *node_modules* folder.
- Make sure you haven't got a *.npmrc* file with *bin-links* options set to false.
- Run *npm install* again.

Should create the executable in *.bin* folder within *node_modules* folder

Comment: when I run "npm run dev" it still can not find the path to cross-env

Comment: Have you got anthing in _./node_modules/.bin/cross-env_ . You should have the cross-env.cmd

Comment: It contains only loose-envify and loose-envify.cmd

Answer (score 1):

First, run:

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json yarn.lock
npm cache clear --force
```

Then run the command

```
npm install cross-env
npm install
```

and then you can run